# this.getClass().getClassLoader() - classes attribute explanation

Tags: java, classloader

I'm looking for a bit of an explanation, I believe I have a class loader issue so I'm trying to see a list of classes that have been loaded by my Axis2 webservice.

As a test at the point in my code where I have the issue I have placed a debug point in the code that is triggered by my remote debug connection to tomcat. In eclipse I have added my own watch expression.

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader()
```

If I then click on the private `classes` member attribute I can see a big list of classes which have obviously been loaded by this `ClassLoader`, but I see no reference to the instance class i.e. the fully qualified class name referenced by `this`. Why? Surely it's been loaded?

Comment: It may have been loaded by a parent. Try climbing up the ClassLoader tree by calling `ClassLoader.getParent()` until you get `null`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon ok if I do `this.getClass().getClassLoader().findClass("foo.bar")` I get a linkage error, I then do as you suggested until I have a null parent, so it ended up being something like `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().findClass("foo.bar")`. This threw a `ClassNotFoundException`, I removed the `getParent()` one by one, every time it throws a `ClassNotFoundException` until I reach the root `ClassLoader` and receive the `LinkageError` again.

Comment: Also if I do `this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("foo.bar")` it works, but if I do `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().loadClass("foo.bar")` it throws a `ClassNotFoundException`